# run code analysis on code checkin

Tags: tfs, code-analysis, checkin

I am working with a c# mvc 4 project where I have code analysis set up on each of the projects within the solution.

I do find this can slow up the time it takes to build the projects. However I do find the analysis extremely beneficial.

I use TFS for source control. Would it be possible not to do such analysis when the projects are building but when the code is being checked in to source control?

Answer (score 1):

You can set Perform Code Analysis to Always in your TFS Build Definition, but disable it in your project files.

Comment: I would like the developer to be altered/prevented from checking in unless code analysis is passed

Comment: Set your build definition's trigger to be a a Gated Check-In then.